# How to activate a virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I want install virtualenv. I type

```
pip install virtualenv
```

and the response is

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\novin\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (20.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<3,>=2 in c:\users\novin\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\novin\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.entry-points-selectable>=1.0.4 in c:\users\novin\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.15.0)
```

And when I want active it, type it "source bin/activate", and the response is "source :

```
The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ source bin/activate
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
```

Comment: Shouldn't you need to create a virtual environment directory first using command `virtualenv <env directory name>` and then you can activate it using `source <env directory name>/bin/activate`?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: `source` doesn't work in PowerShell; that is for linux/unix/macos and the like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+The+term+source+is+not+recognized+as+the+name+of+a+cmdlet%2C+function%2C+script+file%2C+or+operable+program.+Check+the+spelling+of+the+name%2C+or+if+a+path+was

Answer (score 1):

First, make a venv:

```
C:\Users\username> mkvirtualenv web
```

A quick workaround would be to activate cmd like this:

```
PS C:\Users\username> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1151]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\username>workon web
(web) C:\Users\username>
```

If you insist on working in PowerShell, run:

```
PS C:\Users\username> .\\Envs\web\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

Here, Envs is the directory in which your venvs are stored, for me the directory is : C:\Users\username\Envs

But, to use this, you have to Run PowerShell as an Administrator, after that, run:

```
PS C:\Users\username> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

After this you will be able to run your virtual environment.

Comment: thank you. but it dose'nt work!